# How to avoid multiple users page acess at same time and same record in rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, locking, tracking

Would like to display a message when click any product edit page if somebody
already opened/in that same record/page.

how to track users access on edit action for same record?ultimately i want to display message as "somebody already editing this product" to avoid overwrite
process between multiple users.

please share your ideas on it.

Answer (score 2):

Naive solution for this might be adding an association say:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :edited_by, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'edited_by_user_id'
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :edits, class_name: 'Product', foreign_key: 'edited_by_user_id'
end
```

and then:

1. First comes on `/edit` page, set `product.edited_by` to that user.
2. Second user visits `/edit` page. You can check if `edited_by` for that product is set, then show him the message; blocking him to update the same product.
3. Remove the `edited_by` when user has updated the record.

**But this comes at cost**. There are lot of corner cases around this:

1. User might come on edit page and acquire `edited_by` association. But never update the record (thus never giving another user to update the product)
2. In case of some logic exception, `edited_by` might never be reset.
3. Involves devising a strategy when to reset if case #1 occurs.

Thus, I advise using [**Optimistic Locking**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Optimistic.html) instead. You can add a migration with `:lock_version` for your Product model. This will prevent the [stale object](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/StaleObjectError.html) from ever being saved in this scenario, preventing such conflicts.
It will raise the exception `ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError` when User #2(or first) tries to update an old record, which you can use to show your custom message by handling that exeption.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: i knew optimistic locking but want to display message when click on edit and before rendering edit page itself but not when save product.

Comment: I inferred that. But as I mentioned in answer, for that, you may have to go by optimizing first approach, but it has it's own disadvantages. Without it, when user 1 has opened /edit page, you have no way of knowing about that in-memory object, and even if you do, you never know if it will actually be updated in a while.